# Как передать данные из представления в метод?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core

Есть контроллер Customer, в нём метод действия DeleteCustomer.

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel> customers =
        _customerRepository.GetAllCustomers().Select(s => new
        CustomerViewModel
        {
            CustomerId = s.CustomerId,
            Name = s.Name,
            Adress = s.Adress
        });

        return View("Index", customers);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult DeleteCustomer(int id)
    {
        _customerRepository.Delete(id);
        return LocalRedirect("~/Customer/Index");
    }

}
```

Вот ссылка, при нажатии должен сработать метод действия, в метод должен прилететь Id пользователя которого я хочу удалить. Но пишет ошибку 405. Я где то ошибся не могу понять где именно. Буду благодарен за помощь.

```
<a asp-action="DeleteCustomer" asp-route-id="@item.CustomerId">Delete</a>
```

Comment: DeleteCustomer требует POST (аттрибут HttpPost). Тэг "a" это GET по умолчанию

Comment: Через @Html.ActionLink() создавать ссылку ?

Comment: Изменить [HttpPost] на  [HttpGet]. [HttpPost] он для форм

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось через форму

```
    <form asp-action="DeleteCustomer" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@item.CustomerId"/>
                <button type="submit">Delete</button>
    </form>
```